# trying to run a short program, it gives me correct results, but at the end it always give me mysterious error message

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pandas

The following codes extract the state abbreviations from wiki, then I appended to the FMAC/HPI_AL which are then used as key to extract value from a dataset and store them inside a data frame

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd
```

In this software I use quandl and pandas module

```
api_key = 'tVKGSq5NCWt6jr5p1m7Y'
def state_list():
    fiddy_states = pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')
    return fiddy_states[0][0][1:]


def grab_initial_state_data():
    states = state_list()

    main_df = pd.DataFrame()
```

loop through the state abbreviation and append them to another string which together form the keys to extract values from quandl.
        for abbv in states:
            query = "FMAC/HPI_"+str(abbv)
            df = quandl.get(query, authtoken=api_key)
            print(query)
            if main_df.empty:
                main_df = df
            else:
                main_df = main_df.join(df)
                print(main_df)
            print(main_df.head())
    grab_initial_state_data()

First part of the output:

```
FMAC/HPI_AL
                Value
Date
1975-01-31  35.311045
1975-02-28  35.533128
1975-03-31  35.792522
1975-04-30  36.109691
1975-05-31  36.411170
FMAC/HPI_AK
```

After I run the program on my Mac, it produces correct output as expect.
However the system followed it up by printing the following mysterious error message which stops me from doing any future manipulation to the code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "learning_picks.py", line 35, in <module>
    grab_initial_state_data()
  File "learning_picks.py", line 25, in grab_initial_state_data
    main_df = main_df.join(df)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4555, in join
    rsuffix=rsuffix, sort=sort)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4569, in _join_compat
    suffixes=(lsuffix, rsuffix), sort=sort)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 62, in merge
    return op.get_result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 556, in get_result
    rdata.items, rsuf)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4699, in items_overlap_with_suffix
    to_rename)
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index([u'Value'], dtype='object')
```

Any help or insight will be very very very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `main_df` and `df` have an overlapping column name in column, but you haven't specified what to do when this happens.

To fix this error, do:

```
main_df.join(df, lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right')
```

Instead.